# Global and Local Variables in node.js

Tags: node.js, password-recovery

```
global.token='';
app.get('/'+global.token,function(req,res){
                console.log(token);
                res.sendfile('mail3/reg.html');
});
socket.on('email',function(un){
                global.token=randtoken.generate(16);
                console.log(global.token);
                connection.query('update user_login set token="'+token+'" where email="'+un+'";');
});
```

In the following code I am generating a token when a user enters his email ID (for that particular user).Now, when he clicks on the link, the 'password changing' page should open. This is not happening however. In the 'email' event, the token is generated and the user table is updated but is not called in app.get. Please help. I think, I am missing a huge concept here. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

First, don't use `global`, it's really a bad practice

Second, it won't work in your case if you had more then one user

Third:

```
 global.token='';
 app.get('/'+global.token,function(req,res){ ...
```

equals

```
 app.get('/',function(req,res){ ...
```

path is not going to update magically, you should use something like

```
 app.get('/:token', function(req,res){ ...
```

and inside function lookup user by `token`